# How to configure rails with puma on AWS elastic beanstalk app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, puma

I have an EBS app using Ruby and Puma, in my rails app, I have `puma.rb` in `/config/puma.rb` as:

```
workers 2

threads 1, 6

app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)

# Default to production
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
environment rails_env

activate_control_app

# Allow puma to be restarted by `rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart
```

and I have puma gem listed in Gemfile and installed

when I deploy to elastic beanstalk app, I get a successful deployment, and the app state is green, however, when I visit the app link, I get error `This site can’t be reached`

I tried to ssh into the ec2 instance, `puma` command will get:

```
$ puma
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 2.16.0 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Midwinter Nights Trance
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: production
ERROR: No application configured, nothing to run
```

so, what do I miss?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem, i have the same error and I'm at a loss